# SSAS: Two sets specified in the function have different dimensionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to run the following MDX query (I'm newbie in the matter):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Not Null SIGNEDDATA] AS IIF( IsEmpty( [Measures].[SIGNEDDATA] ), 0, [Measures].[SIGNEDDATA] )

SELECT 
{[Measures].[Not Null SIGNEDDATA]} ON COLUMNS,
{[Cuenta].[818000_001],[Cuenta].[818000_G02]} ON ROWS
 FROM [Notas_SIC]
 WHERE ([Auditoria].[AUD_NA],[Concepto].[CONCEPTO_NA],[Entidad].[CCB],
 [Indicador].[INDICADOR_NA],[Interco].[I_NONE],[Moneda].[COP],
 [Tiempo].[2010.01],[Version].[VERSION_NA])
```

Where 818000_001 is a base member of my 'Cuenta' dimension, and 818000_G02 is a node or aggregation. I receive the following message:

"Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality"

What am I doing wrong? If I put the query with only base members (many)  or only differents aggregations, the result is ok as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Andres if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation  to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

By using commas in your WHERE clause, you are trying to create a set out of members from different dimensions.   You should use asterisks to make a CROSSJOIN instead.

So replace this:

```
 WHERE ([Auditoria].[AUD_NA],[Concepto].[CONCEPTO_NA],[Entidad].[CCB],
 [Indicador].[INDICADOR_NA],[Interco].[I_NONE],[Moneda].[COP],
 [Tiempo].[2010.01],[Version].[VERSION_NA])
```

With this:

```
 WHERE ({[Auditoria].[AUD_NA],[Concepto].[CONCEPTO_NA],[Entidad].[CCB]} *
 {[Indicador].[INDICADOR_NA],[Interco].[I_NONE],[Moneda].[COP]} *
 {[Tiempo].[2010.01],[Version].[VERSION_NA]})
```

I added curly braces though I'm not sure if they're absolutely required.

Comment: What he has is not a set. It is tuple. What you gave instead will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe your problem:

```
{[Cuenta].[818000_001],[Cuenta].[818000_G02]} ON ROWS
```

You have put them as a set but you can only make a set out of members with the same dimensionality. From your description it sounds like `[Cuenta].[818000_G02]` is being classed as a different hierarchy which is unexpected.

Is `[Cuenta].[818000_G02]` created using the `Aggregate` function? Can you swap to using the `Sum` function? Does the script then work?

(not a great answer - just more questions?)

Answer (score 0):

```
{[Cuenta].[818000_001],[Cuenta].[818000_G02]}
```

Your problem probably lies in the above statement. As is clear, they could be from different hierarchies(which is not clear from your example and I come to that below).

Try replacing the above with

```
{[Cuenta].[Hierarchy1].[818000_001]} * {[Cuenta].[Hierarchy2].[818000_G02]}
```

where `Hierarchy1` and `Hierarchy2` are the hierarchies to which these members belong. (If you are not sure, just try `{[Cuenta].[818000_001]} * {[Cuenta].[818000_G02]}`). I am assuming that the second aggregate members may be built on a different hierarchy and thus the engine is throwing an error.

It is generally a good habit to always use the fully qualified member name because then the `SSAS` engine has to spend less time in searching for the member.